# Change Case in .dbf file QGIS

Tags: qgis

Asked another question below and this will develop on from this.  The Bedrock 625K BGS mapping is all in UPPERCASE.  It looks clumsey and wrong in the legend.  I wish to change it to Sentence Case.  I know the long winded way is to do each entry manually...there is over 7000 of them...so no.

Working in either QGIS 1.8.4 or 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `title()` function in the QGS field calculator to convert the attributes to title case. e.g.

`title("LEX_D")`

[image: Expression]

Comment: Perhaps i am just having a bad day/week but where do i find the field calculator as above!?

Comment: Right click the layer in the legend and select "Open Attribute Table". Press the "Toggle editing mode" button (looks like a pencil), then the "Open field calculator" button (looks like an abacus). You can either modify an existing field (as shown in the screenshot above) or create a new one.

Comment: Ok well new problem legend stays with old style font as the style was defined under the od way. doh